# Logout after a specific time of inactivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to logout users after they have been inactive for 3 minutes on my app i.e doing nothing for 3 minutes. I have only one `Activity` and it contains multiple `Fragment`s. How can I achieve this? I tried the answers posted on the same topic but nothing worked. Please can anyone be specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Use CountDownTimer

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(15 *60 * 1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           //Some code
        }

        public void onFinish() {
           //Logout
        }
     };
```

When user has stopped any action use timer.start() and when user does the action do timer.cancel()

Answer (score 2):

Each `Activity` has an `onUserInteraction()` function. You can override it and reset a `Runnable`. If there is no user interaction the `Runnable` will be called after 3 minutes. Don't forget to remove `Runnable` onDestory().

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // handle timeout
    }
};

Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    handler.removeCallbacks(r);
    handler.postDelayed(r, 3 * 60 * 1000 );
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(r);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use this as the user might close the activity and the handler will leak the memory.

Comment: @AdibFaramarzi that is why you remove the callback on destroy.

Comment: That wouldn't work. Either you remove the callback onDestory and you lose the callback (and the user will never be logged out when they close the app) or you don't remove it and get memory leak.

Comment: What is thisNavigatorImpl.instance()?

Answer (score 0):

use alarm manager and set alarm  for logout

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Use an alarm manager and have a broadcast receiver upon receiving the alarm and log out from there. When the user does some activity, restart the alarm. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example).
2. have a Service that you can talk to, and send intents `restartTimer`. When the timer reaches zero, log out the user.